# cloudera flume creating an agent from cloudera manager

Tags: cloudera, flume, agent

How can I create an agent from cloudera manager? How can I see that I have an agent started ? indeed, I do not have enough right to work with the command lines

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can set the part "configuration file" with differents agents

Comment: Hello, please expand on your answer as it is unclear how to set the part that you mentioned.

Comment: In Cloudera Manager > Flume > Configuration > part "Configuration file" normally you have a exemple of agent config. What do you want collect ? Log file ? API ?